# If the random variable $X$ is standard Cauchy then so is $1/X$

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem** Prove that $X \in C(0,1) \Rightarrow 1/X \in C(0,1)$ where $C$ is the cauchy distribution.

**Attempt** [image]
I try to prove they have the same density function.

**Question** Is my proof correct?

Comment: Hardly readable. I'd be glad to translate it to LaTeX for you, but at least from a good picture.

Comment: took a new picture. it's the best camera I have...

Comment: To use CDFs might be the most cumbersome approach. Everything works better here, for example using the change of variable/Jacobian theorem which gives the new PDF in terms of the old one.

Answer (score 3):

$$f_{1/X}(x)=\left|-\frac1{x^2}\right|\cdot f_X\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac1{x^2}\cdot \frac1\pi\cdot \frac1{1+\left(\frac1x\right)^2}=\frac1\pi\cdot \frac1{1+x^2}=f_X(x)$$

Comment: Please explain the first =sign. I understand the rest.

Comment: Quote: "for example using the change of variable/Jacobian theorem".

Comment: this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem ?

Comment: ?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability