# Find the distribution function of $Z = X^{-1}$ where $X$ is Cauchy distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a variable that follows a Cauchy distribution. I.e., the density function is given by $$f_X(t) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+t^2)}$$

Then, there is asked to find the probability distribution function $F_Z: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$

where $$F_Z(x) = P(Z \leq x)$$ and $Z = X^{-1}$

I did the following: for $x \neq 0$

$$F_Z(x) = P(Z \leq x) = P(1/X \leq x) = P(X \geq 1/x) = 1 - P(X \leq 1/x)$$
$$= 1 - \int_{- \infty}^{1/x} \frac{1}{\pi(1+t^2)} dt = 1/2 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(1/x)$$

and analoguously $F_Z(0) = 1/2$

but here is my problem:

This can't be the correct answer, because this function is not monotonic, the function is not $1$ at $+ \infty$ and the function is not $0$ at $-\infty$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I asked the same question a couple months ago xD Basically multiplying for a negative number changes the sign of the inequality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333035/321264

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916829/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1/X \leq -1$ is not equivalent to $X \geq -1$. Instead, split up into $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ cases.

Comment: Care to explain why they are not equivalent? I must be missing something trivial.

Comment: For instance, take $X=1$. Then $X \geq -1$ but $1/X \nleq -1$. Alternatively, draw graphs of $y=1/x$ and $y=-1$, and look at which $x$ satisfy $1/x \leq -1$.  Specifically, you can only "flip" the inequality sign like that if the function is monotonically decreasing, but $1/x$ is not decreasing on all of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that for negative $x$ $1/X \leq x \iff 1/x \leq X < 0$ and for positive x was what I wrote correct.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!