# Finding the inverse distribution for a standard cauchy distribution: Is my method correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The standard cauchy distribution was given as follows $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \;\;\;\;\; x\in \mathbb{R}$

I need to find the distribution for $Y= \frac{1}{X}$ and show it is the same as $X$.

I managed to do the problem easily for $y \neq 0$ that $f_Y(y) = (F_X(\frac{1}{y}))'(\frac{1}{y})' = f_X(y)$.

For $y = 0$, can I use the right continuous property of CDFs?

I was hoping to do $F_Y(0) = \lim\limits_{t \to 0+} F_Y(t)$ and then go on to differentiate from there.

Is what I am doing correct? I am unsure because we haven't verified that $F_Y$ is in fact a CDF or something.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovBO5.png]

[If the random variable $X$ is standard Cauchy then so is $1/X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916829/if-the-random-variable-x-is-standard-cauchy-then-so-is-1-x) : In this question, they used a theorem called inverse-jacobian which we have not done yet.

[Cumulative distribution function of Cauchy distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333035/cumulative-distribution-function-of-cauchy-distribution?rq=1) : I also saw this and realise that there are correct methods I can compare to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_Y(y)=f_X(y)$ almost everywhere (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) implies that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. There is no need to worry about $F_Y(0)$.

Some basics: If the densities $f$ and $g$ of $X$ and $Y$ are equal almost everywhere then $P(X \leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x} g(t)dt=P(Y \leq x)$ for all $x$. Changing the value of an integrand at one point or on a set of measure zero does not change the value of the integral.

Comment: We have not looked at lebesgue measures yet...

I can understand that the function is continuous and that $P(Y = 0) = 0$. How would that translate to what $f_Y(0)$ will be?

Comment: But even with basic Calculus and Riemann integration you should know that the value of an integral does not change if you change then value at one point. @user2758186

Comment: I edited my comment just now. 

It does seem true that the value of $f_Y(0)$ does not seem to matter, but, for example, how would I show that $f_Y$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with continuity of $f_Y$ at $0$. Remember that you are asked to find $F_Y$. You are concentrating too much of $f_Y$. You don't have to prove that $f_Y(y)=\frac  1 {\pi} \frac  1{1+y^{2}}$ for every real number $y$. Proving this for $y \neq 0$ fixes the value of $F_Y(y)$ for every $y$ including $0$.  @user2758186

Comment: It took me a while to get it and I got it. The distribution was given to me in the form of a PDF. It does not matter if the PDF jumps at a point, the value of $f_Y(0)$ could very well be arbitary. I perhaps can just say that for the function to be continuous, define $f_Y(0)$ to be equal to the left and right limits (which are equal)