# Probability question with cumulative distribution function and density function calculation.

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with the density function: $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$ $-\infty \le x\le\infty$. 
> We define the random variable $Y=\frac{1}{X}$. Find the density function of $Y$, and find the connection between $X,Y$ distributions.

**My Work:** 
My plan is to find the Cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)$, and then take derivative to get $f_Y(y)$. 
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(\frac{1}{X}\le y)=P(1 \le Xy)\Longrightarrow(\text{When $y> 0$ }) \Longrightarrow =P\left(X \ge \frac{1}{y}\right)=\int_{\frac{1}{y}}^\infty f_X(x) \, dx=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\frac{1}{y}}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{\pi} \left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right]$$
$$\text{For $y < 0$:} \Longrightarrow P\left(X \le \frac{1}{y}\right) =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\frac{1}{y}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{\pi} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]$$

Now I'm not sure if what I did was correct, and I got stuck trying to figure out what happens when $y=0$. And I couldn't figure out what connection there is between the distributions of $X,Y$ until now.

Would appreciate any help or feedback,

thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916829/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333035/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3885604/321264

Comment: I would have written $-\infty<y<+\infty$ rather than $\text{“}{\le}\text{”}. \qquad$

Comment: An explanation for the fact that $1/X$ has the same distribution as $X$ is that this distribution is that of the ratio $Z_1/Z_2$ of independent standard normal random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to address the case where $y=0.$ Probability density functions are not defined pointwise (unlike likelihood functions in statistics, for which the distinction between $\text{“}{<}\text{”}$ and $\text{“}{\le}\text{”}$ sometimes matters in ways in which it does not with density functions). Changing a density function at an isolated point does not change the value of its integral over any set. To say that $f$ is the density function of the probability distribution of a random variable $W$ means only that for every measurable set $A,$
$$
\Pr(W\in A) = \int_A f(x)\,dx.
$$
Altering $f$ at just one point does not alter the integral, so the value  of $f$ at an isolated point isn't really a part of the identity of $f$ at all.

In the case $y>0$ and in the case $y<0,$ the derivative of the c.d.f. with respect to $y$ is
$$
\frac 1 \pi \frac 1 {1+y^2},
$$
and the conclusion is that the probability distribution of $1/X$ is the same as that of $X.$

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, just a question, The derivative in case of $y<0$, is coming out with a negative sign, did I make a mistake calculating the integral or derivative? or there's something I'm missing about the signs of the function?

Comment: @Pwaol : My first suspicion without seeing the details of what you did is that a minus sign was missed whey you applied the chain rule.

Comment: The thing is the $arctan(\frac{1}{y})$ when $y>0$ we have a minus before it, so when I take derivative it cancels with the minus from the chain rule giving the desired result, but when $y<0$ the minus comes from the chain rule, and there's no minus before the $arctan$ there so it doesn't cancel and stays with the result.

Comment: $$
\frac d{dy} \left( - \arctan\frac 1 y \right) = -\frac 1 {1+\left( 1/y \right)^2} \cdot \frac{-1}{y^2} = \frac 1 {y^2+1}.
$$

Comment: Exactly, that's for $y>0$, when $y<0$, $\frac{d}{dy}(\arctan(\frac{1}{y}))=-\frac{1}{y^2+1}$, I calculated the integral above

Comment: $$
\Pr\left( \frac 1 X \le y\right) = \Pr( 1 \ge Xy) = \Pr\left( \frac 1 y \le X \right) = \int_{1/y}^{+\infty} \cdots \ne \int_{-\infty}^{1/y} \cdots
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126324/discussion-between-pwaol-and-michael-hardy).

Comment: @Pwaol : I should actually have written that if $y<0$ then
$$
\Pr\left( \frac 1 X \le y\right) = \Pr( 1 \ge Xy) = \Pr\left( \frac 1 y \le X \right) = \int_{1/y}^0 \cdots.
$$

Comment: Oooooh I see, took my a bunch of time to notice that if $y < 0$ then $\frac{1}{X} < 0$ which means $X < 0$, and when we multiply by $X$ we also flip the inequality and it ends up being the same thing. That's what you've been explaining to me in the comments above also?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.   Of course, you don't *need* to explicitly find the CDF by integration since you would immediately differentiate *that* to find the pdf, which is all that you want.   So to save some work:

$$\begin{align}f_{1/X}(y)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(1/y\leq X)}{\mathrm d y\hspace{10.5ex}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d y}\int_{1/y}^\infty f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex] &= -\dfrac{\mathrm d (1/y)}{\mathrm d y}\cdot f_X(1/y)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{y^2}\cdot\dfrac 1\pi\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+y^{-2}}~\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb R}\\[2ex]\therefore\qquad f_Y(y)&=\dfrac 1\pi\cdot\dfrac 1{y^2+1}~\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb R}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. A trigonmetric identity says:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{If } y>0 \text{ then } & \arctan \frac 1 y = \frac\pi2-\arctan y. \\[8pt]
\text{If } y<0 \text{ then } & \arctan\frac 1 y = -\frac\pi2 - \arctan y.
\end{align}
$$